# Complex inheritance pattern for (JSON) data contracts

Tags: c#, json, oop, inheritance, json.net

I started off with a simple data model:

```
{
    "Make" : "Honda",
    "Model" : "Civic",
    "Engine" : {
        "Location" : "Front"
    }
}
```

This object satisfied my use cases, until I got an additional requirement, so it became:

```
{
    "Make" : "Honda",
    "Model" : "Civic",
    "FuelType" : "Gasoline",
    "Engine" : {
        "Location" : "Front",
        "MPG" : 39
    }
}
```

OR

```
{
    "Make" : "Tesla",
    "Model" : "Model S",
    "FuelType" : "Electric",
    "Engine" : {
        "Location" : "Back",
        "Range" : 300
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I can't override using a derived return type in C#, so the following class structure won't work:

```
abstract class Car { abstract Engine Engine; }

class GasolineCar : Car { override GasolineEngine Engine; }

class ElectricCar : Car { override ElectricEngine Engine; }

abstract class Engine { string Location; }

class GasolineEngine : Engine { int MPG; }

class ElectricEngine : Engine { int Cells; }
```

Is there a similar recommended way to model this data pattern? Requirements are:

1. I can easily deserialize it using JSON.NET
2. I can use the base Car & Engine types 90% of the time and only cast it when type-specific fields are needed.

*Note: Please don't offer alternate solutions specifically for the above example. I know nothing about cars, and my real use case definitely needs to use this pattern or something similar.*

Answer (score 2):

I think you are definitely over complicating your classes. Why not simple use these classes, the json can be de-serialised to these classes easily

```
class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}

class Engine
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string MPG { get; set; }
    public string Range { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This specific scenario is irrelevant. What if both engine types have the same field name but with different data types?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The engine data types ? At the end of the day you need a class which can be mapped to a json object. The properties on the json need to be mapped to a property on the class. If there is a new property on the json there will be a new property on the class.

Answer (score 0):

Generally methods are these the get overridden fields cannot be overridden . So you have to override your Get - Set Methods

```
public abstract class Car { public virtual Engine Engine { get; set; } }

public class GasolineCar : Car {
    private GasolineEngine _engine;
    public override Engine Engine { get { return _engine; } set { this._engine = (GasolineEngine)value; } }
}

public class ElectricCar : Car
{
    private ElectricEngine _engine;
    public override Engine Engine { get { return _engine; } set { this._engine = (ElectricEngine)value; } }
}
public abstract class Engine { public string Location; }

public class GasolineEngine : Engine { int MPG; }

public class ElectricEngine : Engine { int Cells; }
```

Alternatively if Type restriction is what matters .

```
public abstract class Car<T> { public virtual T Engine { get; set; } }

public class GasolineCar : Car<GasolineEngine> {}

public class ElectricCar : Car<ElectricEngine>{}
public abstract class Engine { public string Location; }

public class GasolineEngine : Engine { int MPG; }

public class ElectricEngine : Engine { int Cells; }
```